# How do I drag a div if someone clicks on a input within the `draggable` div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have the following html and js (view the jsfiddle below).

I have the jquery drag event binding on dom ready to `.control-group`.

If a user clicks and drags anywhere except the input (within the div), they can drag the div as expected, but if they click in the input, it selects the input for text entering, (and doesn't allow us to drag it).

I want to be able to have the user click ANYTHING within the div, and the WHOLE div should be able to be dragged.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="textInput">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <!-- If someone clicks on this input, the whole div should still be draggable -->
        <!-- Its ok if the input is not usable, thats the point!, Its just for show -->
        <input id="textInput" name="textInput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder"/>
        <p class="help-block">you have an error!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery (Dom Ready):

```
$('.control-group').draggable();
```

So i'm looking for the event to "bubble" up to the `.control-group` div. *(If I got that right?!)*

[View the JSFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/8stpE/) http://jsfiddle.net/8stpE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
$('.control-group').draggable( { cancel : " " } );
```

Remember that draggable takes a lot of arguments, and you can look them up [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: that makes it so the textinput would be focusable, he wants the opposite he wants it so it doesnt become focused,and allows for dragging even when you have clicked and dragged from the input box

Comment: This works just as I require!, The input never receives focus, and you can drag the whole div on click (even on the input), I just have to add a `cursor:pointer;` to achieve what I want!.. Thanks! I would upvote, but I require 15 reps! +1

Comment: It seems its the same either way? (with `textInput` or '' (empty))

Comment: That's only because the 'cancel' option works on tag types, not on ids.  It's less confusing to use the empty quotes.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, I shall read over the docs more carefully, thanks!